# Coreferencing in Google NLP API

Tags: nlp, google-cloud-nl

I was testing the Google NLP API and found out that it works only for a single sentence. I was wondering if it works for multiple sentences at once with coreference as that would help a lot. I know about Stanford Coreference resolution and other tools but want to know if Goggle  NLP API does it?
Or can someone recommend a good accurate tool for coreference resolution.

Answer (score 1):

co-referencing does work across sentences, but it's very conservative. For example, try this sentence:
Donald Trump is the president of united states. Mr Trump is responsible for running the government.
In the try-it box here: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/

You can see that "Donald Trump", "president", and "Mr Trump" are all mentions of the same entity.

Comment: Thank you for reply Mona. Tried the above sentence that works. But it does not work for pronouns. Have you tried that?

Comment: Correct, it doesn't. We don't expose co-reference pronouns at all.